# Calculate date difference in weeks (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp, difference

I have two strings:

> 1387050870

and

> 2012-12-15

How can i calculate the difference between these two dates in weeks (52)?

I tried `Math.round(1387050870-(Math.round(new Date('2012-12-15').getTime()/1000))/604800)`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: "doesn't seem to work." What does that mean? Error? NaN?

Comment: I'll answer my question. I got NaN because '2012-15-12' is an "Invalid Date"

Comment: Changed my post. It returns everything, but not the expected result.

Comment: Tips: There is to need to used ` getTime` to convert it to millisecond.

Comment: Seems like your time string is not [rfc2822](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#page-14) compliant

Comment: 1) Gregorian calendars don't have a 15th month and typical `####-##-##` formats are parsed as `YYYY-MM-DD` when supported. 2) Order of operations divides before subtracting without grouping.

Comment: And also the date format Date accept is Date(year, month, day)

Comment: Okay, good to know. However, it returns a number, but i have no idea, what.

Comment: I've already fixed it. It was just a typo in the question. `new Date('2012-12-15')` returns a correct value. Time is not relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The JavaScript Date object accepts milliseconds as its constructor, so convert first then try:

```
var a  = new Date(1387050870 * 1000);
var b = new Date("2012-12-15");
var weeks = Math.round((a-b)/ 604800000);
```

Which makes `weeks` 2239, which sounds close, since b is almost 43 years later * 52 weeks.

Comment: Returns 2239 instead of 52 :)

Comment: @user2368182 I got "Fri Jan 16 1970 17:17:30 GMT-0800 (PST)" from `new Date(1387050870);`

Comment: if first value is a unix timestamp need to multiply by 1000 first

Comment: Ah, you didnt specify the timestamp type, so I assumed milliseconds

Comment: @charlietfl Exactly. I think it should probably be `new Date(1387050870000);` which gives 2014

Comment: `var a  = new Date(1387050870000);
var b = new Date("2012-12-15");
var weeks = Math.round((b-a)/ 604800000);` returns -52

Comment: @charlietfl That's it :) Now, i get -52, which is correct. Ty.

Comment: Just a little thing: The timestamp doesn't need to be a Date object.

Comment: Use Math.floor instead of Math.round

Comment: It depends on what do we means by different of weeks between two dates, do we mean the difference of week as a time interval difference or a calender interval as a difference, using the chosen solution for this questions, we get a 0 week difference for 4/01/2015 and 5/01/2015 but there is one week calender difference between the two

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var date1 = new Date(1387050870 * 1000);
var date2 = new Date("2012-12-15");
var dif = Math.round(date1-date2);
alert(Math.round(dif/1000/60/60/24/7));
```

[Here it is on jsfiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/K7uCr/)